# Do the Runelords still exist in Starfinder?

Tags: lore, starfinder

(This may go unanswered for a while due to not much Starfinder lore being released, but I feel like it's worth asking now.)

After the conclusion of Rise of New Thassilon (the most recent Adventure Path) (spoiler alert),

> the only two runelords who survived were Belimarius and Sorshen, with a new faction emulating the runelords' magic and trying to become runelords as well. It's likely that at least one person from that faction succeeded before the Gap.

It's known that Starfinder is in Pathfinder's direct future, and all runelords are immortal.

(more spoilers)

> In addition, Sorshen has the immortal ability from being 9th mythic tier, so it's incredibly unlikely that she in particular died from violent means.

**Has any information been revealed that any runelords are still around as of Starfinder? Any evidence to the contrary?**

Answer (score 5):

### It is unclear so far

The only reference we have about the runelords are from *Incident at Absalom Station*, which mentions one of the [Seven Swords of Sin](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Alara%27hai), [Ungarato](https://starfinderwiki.com/sf/Ungarato).

> Which was reforged into a gun.

Considering how those weapons are somehow connected to their runelords, that suggests to me that the [runelord of gluttony](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Goparlis) is still around, or someone else who inherited his power.

[James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1363?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#68102) has hinted that it's possible for another person to become a runelord, in specific circumstances:

> To be a runelord, you need to have a Thassilon and an empire to rule. Simply killing Karzoug and saying "I'm a runelord now" doesn't really count much for the swords. Maybe if you prove to the swords over the course of a few years or decades... but not all at once.

But has also said [he wouldn't like to see them in Starfinder](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=1363?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#68102):

> Runelords are a Pathfinder thing, not a Starfinder thing. I'd rather not have the runelords play a role in Starfinder at all. I'd rather Starfinder make its own new built-in NPCs.

But we know that, despite being Paizo's Creative Director, he is not part of the Starfinder team, nor has the decision over what happens with the canon of Starfinder, such as the destruction of Golarion.